# Качество картинки при SET_WALLPAPER, что делаю не так?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите в чем проблема?
В ImageView добавляю картинку с помощью Pisacco и для эффекта увеличиваю ее ширину на 200px, все хорошо и картинка выглядит отлично.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При клике по кнопке нужно установить ее в качестве фонового изображения.
Я беру эту картинку из ImageView, получаю ее размер, получаю размер дисплея, делаю расчеты

```
// Ширина и высота дисплея
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public List<Integer> getScreen() {

    List<Integer> size = new ArrayList<>();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    final Point point = new Point();
    try {
        display.getSize(point);
    } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) {
        // Older device
        point.x = display.getWidth();
        point.y = display.getHeight();

    }
    size.add(point.x);
    size.add(point.y);

    return size;
}


// Обрезаю и устанавливаю картинку
public void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap, List<Integer> size) {

    Log.d(TAG, "width display: " + size.get(0)); // 1280 - ширина дисплея
    Log.d(TAG, "height display: " + size.get(1)); // 720 - высота дисплея
    Log.d(TAG, "width bitmap: " + bitmap.getWidth()); // 1480 - ширина картинки
    Log.d(TAG, "height bitmap: " + bitmap.getHeight()); // 720 - высота картинки

    Bitmap dstBmp;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()){

        dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                bitmap.getWidth()/2 - size.get(0)/2, // x = 100
                0, // y = 0
                size.get(0), // width = 1280
                size.get(1) // height = 720
        );

    } else {

        dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                0,
                size.get(1)/2 - bitmap.getWidth()/2,
                size.get(0),
                size.get(1)
        );
    }

    WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    try {
        wm.setBitmap(dstBmp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

При повторном обновлении ImageView с обработанной картинкой все в порядке, ширина уменьшилась на 200px и качество не пострадало. (img.setImageBitmap(dstBmp);)

Сворачиваю приложение и вижу такую картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите новичку, что не так делаю и с чем это связано? Такое ощущение что картинка растягивается в два раза по ширине и высоте при установке ее на фон.

Comment: Обои всегда увеличивается. Проверьте на любой картинке из вашей галереи  и увидите

Comment: Как тогда быть? Есть какая то закономерность на сколько именно увеличивается картинка по высоте и ширине, чтобы сделать ее больше соблюдая пропорции?